# Stop at the first occurence of a character

Tags: java, charat

I want to only remove 'a' in " brealdeke "
This program works, it prints " breldeke " but if I were to put
" brealdeake" with 2 'a' in this string, it goes berserk and prints : breldeakebrealdeke How to fix it ? Thanks
I really want it to look this this :

```
class Example {
    public static String suppression(char c, String s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == c) {
                int position = i;
                for (int a = 0; a < position; a++) {
                    System.out.print(s.charAt(a));
                }
                for (int b = position + 1; b < s.length(); b++) {
                    System.out.print(s.charAt(b));
                }
            }

        }
        return "";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // prints "breldeke"
        System.out.println(suppression('a', "brealdeke"));
        // prints "breldeakebrealdeke"
        System.out.print(suppression('a', "brealdeake"));
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to delete the first occurrence of the first character that is repeated?

Comment: Hmm not " repeated " , I don't know how to explain it
I'm the one who choose the letter that has to be removed
Here is a few example 
'a' in " Software " --> prints Softwre 
or 'o' in "Software" --> prints Sftware 
or 'o' in "Tomato" --> prints Tmato

Answer (score 1):

You could try :

```
"banana".replaceFirst("a", "");
```

This returns `bnana`

**EDIT**: Hopefully, this doesn't include anything you haven't been taught yet

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "banana";
    String strippedWord = "";
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (word.charAt(i) == 'a' && !found) found = !found;
        else strippedWord += word.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(strippedWord);
}
```

This prints `bnana`

**EDIT2** : You said you wanted it in a function, the same applies :

```
public static String suppression(char c, String word) {
    String strippedWord = "";
    boolean charRemoved = false;    // This is a boolean variable used to know when the char was skipped!
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        // If the current letter is for example 'a' and we haven't yet skipped the char, skip this char we're at 
        if (word.charAt(i) == c && charRemoved == false) charRemoved = true;
        else strippedWord += word.charAt(i);
    }
    return strippedWord;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // prints "breldeke"
    System.out.println(suppression('a', "brealdeke"));
    // prints "breldeake"
    System.out.print(suppression('a', "brealdeake"));
}
```

Comment: I always forget Java has all of these almost impractical operations.

Comment: HI thank you for your answer but since we haven't been taught yet about 
" .replace " at school they won't allow us use that :s

So far, we know : charAt() , .length() , stringEquals

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate what you are doing for me thanks a lot but never seen found either :s
I've edited  my post, tried to make it less messy if you could take a look at it again thanks

Comment: `found` is just a boolean variable, here I've changed the code to put it in your function!

Answer (score 0):

Additional variables OK?

I'd do it like this personally:

```
public static String removeFirstLetter(string s, char c)
{
   String word = "";
   Bool foundChar = false;

   for ( int i = 0; i<s.length();i++) {
      if (s.charAt(i).toLower() != c)
      {
         word += s.char(i);
      }
    else
    {
       if (foundChar == false){
           foundChar = true;
       }  
       else
       {
           word += s.char(i);
       }
     }
   }
}

 System.out.print(word);
```

Comment: HI thank you too for your answer ,
but since we haven't been taught yet about " toLower " at school they won't allow us use that :s So far, we know : charAt() , .length() , stringEquals

Comment: @Blebhebhe You could leave that out if case isn't a concern

Comment: Thanks appreciate it, we do know " boolean " but my homework is about using a function , may you take a look at my post again, someone edited it to make it look less messy

Comment: All you'd need to do then is wrap the code above in a method / function to call. I'll update it.